# simulating touchscreen clicks in embedded linux

Tags: c, linux, embedded, device

I need to send events to input1 in order to simulate touchscreen events.

this is the output of  "cat /proc/bus/input/devices":

> ```
> I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
> N: Name="mxc_ts"
> P: Phys=
> S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input1
> U: Uniq=
> H: Handlers=event1 
> B: EV=b
> B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> B: ABS=1000003
> ```

tried to cat /dev/input/ts0 but the output isn't readable.

Could you please help me to simulate a ts click?

PS: we have no gtk packages installed.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before by writing a small kernel module for injecting input core events from userspace. If you need to support platforms that aren't running X (we used it for automated testing of Qt/E apps), that kind of approach is probably your best bet.

Comment: I thought that other simpler solutions exists. I will probably do the same. thanks.